# Testing in convolution neural networks

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am getting error like this. Please let me know how to load the image in this code.

```
def prepare(filepath):
IMG_SIZE = 70  # 50 in txt-based
img_array = cv2.imread(filepath, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
new_array = cv2.resize(img_array, (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE))
return new_array.reshape(-1, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 1)

model = tf.keras.models.load_model("64x3-CNN.model")
prediction = model.predict([prepare('doggo.jpg')])
print(prediction)  # will be a list in a list.
print(CATEGORIES[int(prediction[0][0])])
```

Error:

```
ValueError Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-1-1d42891fac0e> 
in <module> 14 model = tf.keras.models.load_model("cnn") 15 ---> 16 
prediction = model.predict([prepare('ct.jpg')]) 17 print(prediction) # will 
be a list in a list. 18 print(CATEGORIES[int(prediction[0][0])]) ValueError: 
Error when checking input: expected conv2d_9_input to have shape (100,100,1) 
but got array with shape (70, 70, 1)
```

Comment: Where is the error!, Please show us that.

Answer (score 0):

i found the answer. error was because of image size

```
  IMG_SIZE = 100 # 50 in txt-based
```